# Decrypting assembly instructions before executing

Tags: c, windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I am working on a project where my main executable has another executable attached to it. It loads all of its imports, does relocations, and maps it. After that it calls the entry point where it is now executing the 2nd program.

Before this I register a Vectored Exception Handler

```
LONG NTAPI veh_handler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptInfo) {
    // Start single stepping
    pExceptInfo->ContextRecord->EFlags |= 0x100;
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, &veh_handler);
    // Load the 2nd program
    
    // Start executing the other program
    ((void(*)())retAddr);
    return 0;
}
```

The second program that is attached looks like

```
int main() {
    __debugbreak();
    printf("Hello World\n");
    // ... some other random code
    return 0;
}
```

So when it begins executing it will hit the debug break and cause execution to go into my exception handler. From there I set the flag to single step each instruction. From here I can watch the RIP move while also viewing the executable in PE Bear.

What I would do is set the second program text section to `PAGE_NOACCESS`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, &veh_handler);
    // Load the 2nd program
    
    // Start executing the other program
    DWORD protect;
    VirtualProtect(retAddr, textsize, PAGE_NOACCESS, *protect);
    ((void(*)())retAddr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now instead of relying on the `__debugbreak()` since it would be encrypted, it will attempt to read the memory and it can't so it will go to my exception handler and from there I can set it back to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.

My question would be if the entire `.text` section of the 2nd program was encrypted, could I decrypt each instruction before continuing execution? I have looked at some length disassemblers which would give me the length of the instruction but I think even if I know the length I will run into issues where I see something like

```
48FF255A080000 JMP QWORD PTR [RIP + 0X85A]
```

So I would have to dig deeper and decrypt whatever is at RIP + 0X85A.

Does anything exist like this? This is a project that I decided to pick up while digging into Assembly as a beginner.

I have some rough code that I put together using a length disassembler and I am able to get the length of each instruction. However when dealing with indirect addressing I am having a hard time figuring out a way to determine what to do.

Comment: You will get an exception for the data access as well so you could just decrypt that separately. Yeah well since you set the page permissions back that is not necessarily true if the referenced address is in the same page.

Comment: I believe most compilers will put data into separate sections (even though read-only could go into the `.text`) so for a toy project you could assume that. At least until you decode the instructions enough to extract any memory operands.

Comment: `So I would have to dig deeper and decrypt whatever is at RIP + 0X85A.` Yes, `GetThreadContext` to get RIP. `Does anything exist like this?` Yes, emulators (VMs, packers, obfuscators) and most analysis tools do this. Also, you're missing a lot of things to get this to work for anything but the simplest programs. E.g. global variables and TLS *will* lead to crashes. By the way, instructions are usually **decoded**, unless you're writing an obfuscator that would actually do some decrypting. If you are writing a (de)obfuscator, then this question is probably beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: In the VEH the ```pExceptInfo``` struct contains all the registers so I can get RIP from there. I think keeping everything sync'd for multi threaded apps would not be to hard. Right now I am just XORing every byte against a byte to obfuscate it and then deobfuscate it. My biggest issue right now is figuring out every scenario where indirect memory addressing is happening. This requires me to not only deobfuscate the RIP but also the locations that are being referenced.

Comment: @getunstuckaq Yes, that is a problem. It's easy for RIP relative and absolute addressing but anything requiring any other registers is going to be difficult since those values are usually only known at runtime. You're likely not going to find help here, so perhaps try [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)?